# Express Module not found upon deploying web app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have just started backend development and I'm trying to deploy a web app to heroku. The app is working completely fine locally, but upon deploying it to heroku I'm getting the following error. It's saying express module is not found. Why is this happening and can I get a solution to this please?

```
2020-10-13T20:50:55.872846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984395+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984407+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984407+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984408+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984408+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984409+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984409+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984410+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984410+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984411+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984411+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984411+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:2:15)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984412+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984412+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984413+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984413+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984413+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984414+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-10-13T20:50:57.984414+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
```

If any additional details are needed to answer the question, please do ask.

Comment: Do you have `express` listed as a dependency in your `package.json`?

Comment: No I do not have it mentioned in the file.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  }

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the dependency in your `package.json` then you need to run:

```
npm install express --save
```

and redeploy to Heroku.

Comment: I have installed express using the same and the app works fine locally. It's just that after deploying it to heroku, I'm getting this error

Comment: but if you don't have anything in your `package.json` regarding `express`, how will heroku know to install it?

Comment: Yes I understand your point, but if I am using express, and my app works fine, shouldn't the express dependency be added to package.json automatically? Or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: you could have express installed globally. If you run `npm install express --save` if will automatically add the dependency to your `package.json`.

Comment: I wrote the dependency in package.json myself, and now it works. Must've been a glitch that it didnt get mentioned automatically. Thanks for the help.